# Shortest Path algorithm isnt working as intended

Tags: java, graph

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;

import ca.mcmaster.cas.se2aa4.a4.pathfinder.graph.Edge;
import ca.mcmaster.cas.se2aa4.a4.pathfinder.graph.Graph;
import ca.mcmaster.cas.se2aa4.a4.pathfinder.graph.Node;

public class GraphShortestPath implements PathFinder {
    private Graph graph;
    Map<Node, Double> distances = new HashMap<>(); // tentative distances from start node to each node
    Map<Node, Node> predecessors = new HashMap<>(); // predecessors of each node in the shortest path
    
    public GraphShortestPath(Graph graph) {
        this.graph = graph;
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<Node> findPath(Node start, Node end) {
        

        PriorityQueue<Node> unvisitedNodes = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingDouble(distances::get)); // nodes not visited yet
        Set<Node> visitedNodes = new HashSet<>(); // visited nodes
        
        // initialize tentative distances and add all nodes to unvisited nodes
        for (Node node : graph.getNodesList()) {
            if (node.equals(start)) {
                distances.put(node, 0.0);
            } else {
                distances.put(node, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
            }
            unvisitedNodes.offer(node);
        }
        
        // loop until we reach the end node or there are no more nodes to visit
        while (!unvisitedNodes.isEmpty()) {
            Node current = unvisitedNodes.poll();
            
            
            if (current.equals(end)) {

                // we have found the shortest path, reconstruct it using predecessors and return it
                List<Node> shortestPath = new ArrayList<>();
                Node node = end;
                System.out.println(predecessors.size());
                System.out.println();
                while (node != null) {
                    System.out.println(node.getId());
                    shortestPath.add(0, node);
                    node = predecessors.get(node);
                    
                }
                return shortestPath;
            }
            visitedNodes.add(current);
            for (Edge edge : current.getOutEdges()) {
                Node neighbor = edge.getDestination();
                if (visitedNodes.contains(neighbor)) {
                    continue;
                }
                double tentativeDistance = distances.get(current) + edge.getWeight();
                if (tentativeDistance < distances.get(neighbor)) {
                    distances.put(neighbor, tentativeDistance);
                    predecessors.put(neighbor, current);
                    unvisitedNodes.remove(neighbor);
                    unvisitedNodes.offer(neighbor);
                }
            }
        }
        
        // end node is not reachable from start node
        System.out.println("no path was found");
        return null;



    }
}
```

this data structure for finding the shortest path will sometimes not construct the path correctly, after it throws the end node in to the shortest path array list, where it does 'node = predesccors.get(node)' it returns null when there should be a predesccor b4 it, how to fix this? this doesnt happen all the time, for example when I manually create a graph like the following:

```
import java.util.List;

import ca.mcmaster.cas.se2aa4.a4.pathfinder.graph.Graph;
import ca.mcmaster.cas.se2aa4.a4.pathfinder.graph.Node;
import ca.mcmaster.cas.se2aa4.a4.pathfinder.path.GraphShortestPath;
import ca.mcmaster.cas.se2aa4.a4.pathfinder.path.PathFinder;

public class Main {
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Graph graph = new Graph();

        graph.addNode(0);
        graph.addNode(1);
        graph.addNode(2);
        graph.addNode(3);
        graph.addNode(4);
        graph.addNode(5);
        graph.addNode(6);
        graph.addNode(7);
        graph.addNode(8);
        graph.addNode(9);
        graph.addNode(10);
        graph.addNode(11);
        graph.addNode(12);
        graph.addNode(13);
        graph.addNode(14);
        graph.addNode(15);
        graph.addNode(16);
        graph.addNode(17);
        graph.addNode(18);
        graph.addNode(19);
        graph.addNode(20);
        
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(0), graph.getNode(1));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(0), graph.getNode(7));

        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(1), graph.getNode(0));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(1), graph.getNode(7));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(1), graph.getNode(2));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(1), graph.getNode(8));

        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(2), graph.getNode(1));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(2), graph.getNode(8));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(2), graph.getNode(9));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(2), graph.getNode(3));

        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(3), graph.getNode(2));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(3), graph.getNode(9));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(3), graph.getNode(4));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(3), graph.getNode(10));

        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(4), graph.getNode(3));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(4), graph.getNode(10));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(4), graph.getNode(11));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(4), graph.getNode(5));

        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(5), graph.getNode(4));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(5), graph.getNode(11));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(5), graph.getNode(12));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(5), graph.getNode(6));

        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(6), graph.getNode(5));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(6), graph.getNode(12));

        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(8), graph.getNode(1));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(8), graph.getNode(2));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(8), graph.getNode(9));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(8), graph.getNode(16));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(8), graph.getNode(15));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(8), graph.getNode(14));
        graph.addEdge(graph.getNode(8), graph.getNode(7));

        PathFinder path = new GraphShortestPath(graph);
        List<Node> l = path.findPath(graph.getNode(0), graph.getNode(6));

        for(Node n: l){
            System.out.println(n.getId());
        }




    }

}
```

this will provide me with the correct shortest path, but sometimes im finding an issue where the shortest path returned to me is just the destination node and Im not quite sure why that is happening

I tried to add the predesccor node manually when reaching the end node but that didnt work.

Comment: this is a bit too much code to ask people to read here. I would recommend adding some print commands showing current state in various places in your code to try to visualize what's happening, and see where it goes wrong. Isolate the problem to a particular spot. My guess is you will find your solution this way.

Comment: For example, at each node visit, print the node you are visiting and the entire graph, and print visited nodes and unvisited nodes. Do this for a short graph which produces the wrong result and see what's up

Comment: " Map<Node, Node> predecessors = new HashMap<>(); // predecessors of each node in the shortest path"  This looks wrong.  Each node has only one predecessor, the previous node on the shortest path so far found to the node.